# Is "s" at the end of "warrants" and "forensics" used to create a name of a department?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Here's an example from the movie se7en: "You girls have forensics waiting outside.

..another one from the movie "American Gangster": "You called in the warrants, right? So where are they?"

Comment: The reason we name the relevant *office / department* using the plural noun form is because those departments *deal with* multiple ***Warrants*** and ***Forensic Analyses*** (which in the latter case is a bit of a mouthful, so people just discard the "head noun" and attach pluralising ***s*** to the preceding adjective instead).

Comment: ...but I think you've misunderstood the cited "warrants" usage. It looks to me like a slightly non-standard way of saying *You called **for** the warrants [to be drawn up and given to us].* I'm not sure any organisations have a department called "Warrants".

Comment: Along the same lines as FumbleFingers, I'd propose that "you called in the warrants" might be more explicitly stated as: "you called in [an order for] the warrants"

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I did misunderstand that one, true. "Call in" in this example means: to order something by phone, and warrants are just, well, warrants =]

Comment: Actually, the full OED says the ***s*** in ***forensics, optics, politics, ethics, physics,...*** is all down to the morphology of their Latin roots *"...which might be taken as feminine singular or neuter plural; hence there was in medieval Latin considerable fluctuation in the grammatical treatment of these words".* So we end up today with ***economics*** and ***linguistics*** (but not ***musics*** :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I know it's a little off-topic, but is the OED premium subscription worth it for someone like me who's trying to learn English as a second language?

Comment: @StaticBounce: It depends how deep your pockets are! [For an annual rate of **$295**, you'll have full unrestricted access to the OED Online.](https://www.oed.com/public/howtosub/how-to-subscrib) Seriously, No - it's not designed to teach English to non-native speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not the case with your examples, as far as I can tell.

The noun "forensics" is always written in the plural form when it has this meaning. Here is [M-W's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forensic):

> **forensics** plural in form but singular or plural in construction: the application of scientific knowledge to legal problems
> *especially*: scientific analysis of physical evidence (as from a crime scene)

The second example is harder to decipher without more context (I haven't seen that movie in years and don't recall that scene), but it appears that the character is referring to actual warrants and not to any department. I suspect that this is the definition that is meant (also [from M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warrant)):

> a precept or writ issued by a competent magistrate authorizing an officer to make an arrest, a seizure, or a search or to do other acts incident to the administration of justice

Comment: Chat Gpt provided the same answer as you but I don't understand **how "scientific analysis of physical evidence" can wait outside?**  People can wait outside but abstract things like analysis? I hope you know what I mean

Comment: @StaticBounce It's metonymy, referring to people by their specialty (or occupation, employer, etc.). So it could be translated as "people from the forensics department", but surely the department itself wasn't waiting outside.